# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "?" Error appears just on one PC and on other PC the Program works using Spyder 4

Tags: python, spyder, importerror

I have a Program in Python that works fine on my Laptop but on my Tower PC it throws an import error

Program structure

1. parent folder

   - folder1

     - file1.py
   - file2.py

I want to import a variable form file2.py into file1.py. File2.py uses other files in the parent folder.
If i use the import code in file1.py

```
from file2.py import variable.file2
```

i get a ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named "file2.py"

I tried several things on my Stand PC

1. Make a relative import of the file2.py with:

`from .file2.py import variable.file2`

But get an ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

1. Make **init**.py files in every folder, but that didn't change anything

On my Laptop the import Error doesn't appear, although the program structure and environment should be the same

I use Spyder 4 with a virtual environment where i installed Python 3.7.9

The other packages who maybe be relevant in this program are

```
import os
import sys
```

Does anybody have any ideas? Do i have to change the Pythonpath or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue, program structure was not the same. So my Fault. This question can be closed.